# A div straight after the body causes a large top margin in firefox only

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have looked over previous answers, but they're all related to pages where they are floating elements, etc. This is a simple page with one `h1` and `p` element:

```
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <h1 id = "main_title">Chocolate Eclairs</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <p>A simple french treat.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

The CSS (for clarity):

```
body{   background-color: pink; margin: 0; }
h1{ background-color: blue;}
.main{ background-color: white;}
```

This produces a gap at the top of the page, and `body` is starting not right at the top.

[image: Starting with a div]
If I comment out the first `div` element, so that it starts with `h1` first, it disappears:

[image: Starting without a div]

So, how do I fix this? My page relies on starting with a div element, and firefox (26.0) is the only browser producing this.

Comment: Check the computed styles on the h1 - there'll probably be a margin-top. explicitly set that to 0 in your css

Comment: It's not just related to Firefox, every browser do the same. @MarcB gave the answer for your problem.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks, that solved it! Weird how I needed to change the `h1` element, even though it shows the `body` as starting under. Is this the same bug as [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=451791) or is that something else?

Comment: @regulus I have tried it on Chrome, IE, Safari - none produced any extra margin on top apart from firefox

Comment: @tgun926: I don't think it's a bug. If the first child of an element has a margin and certain other criteria are met, that margin is moved to that parent element. You may be experiencing differences due to quirks mode. Try adding an HTML5 `DOCTYPE` and you may get more consistent behavior between browsers.

Comment: @icktoofay Ah, you're right - the html5 `DOCTYPE` certainly did reproduce it on the other browers I tested it on. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've been bitten by [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). Under certain circumstances (elaborated upon in great detail in [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)), the margin of a child element (in this case, the `h1`) will be transferred to the enclosing element. However, your document has no `DOCTYPE`, so browsers go into quirks mode, where not all rules are obeyed. It seems that in this case Firefox still obeys that rule, but the others might not.

The solution is to

1. add an appropriate `DOCTYPE` at the top of your file

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   ```
2. add rules to remove the margin from the `h1`

   ```
   h1 { margin: 0; }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

use this css,just added a margin:0px in the h1 style

```
body{   background-color: pink; margin: 0; }
h1{ background-color: blue;margin:0px}
.main{ background-color: white;}
```

and the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/meLcN/) is here

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the default styles on the elements. You need to take a look at css resets, a popular one is [Eric Meyer's reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Usually what I do, is something like this at the top of your stylesheet.

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;

 /* A better box model */
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Selects all elements, and removes margin and padding. Also using the box-sizing:border-box. Which is a much more intuitive CSS box model. Where padding, and borders don't add to the actual set width of your elements. [You can read more via paul irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the same style as body to html:

```
html,body{   background-color: pink; margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Guys I found the solution to this it's very easy Please make sure that there is a space between `<!` And `DOCTYPE And Html>` and then `margin:0px;` in the body.

```
  <! DOCTYPE html>
...
<body style="margin:0px;">
...
```

Answer (score -2):

By default, the heading tags H1, H2, etc. have top margins. Top margins are not correctly contained in Firefox.

Try h1{padding:0;margin:0} to debug the issue. Then use padding-top to replace margin-top.

I'd advice you against using reset sheets. They come with side effects.